How add a new device in Android Device Manager with root credentials?
I test a bunch of apps with the emulator in Visual Studio with Google Play Store.

What I want is to have access to the emulator as root to inspect the /data/data folder. When I add a new device, there is no option for that.

Is it possible to have an emulator with root access? If yes, how can I do it?

Not clear if you saw: ADB root is not working on emulator (cannot run as root in production builds)

You can also refer to this doc to see adb: Android Debug Bridge.


What I want is to have access to the emulator as root to inspect the /data/data folder.

You can try the following steps:

Start android emulator. In Visual Studio, open the adb command prompt by selecting the menu option: Tools > Android > Android Adb Command Prompt.

In the command prompt, enter adb root command:


C:\Users\admin\source\repos\your_project_name>adb root


After rooting successfully, enter adb shell. If see #, it means that you have permission to view the files in the directory:

C:\Users\admin\source\repos\your_project_name>adb shell
your_emulator_name:/ #


Enter cd /data/data to go to /data/data directory， then enter ls -al to see the file list:

C:\Users\admin\source\repos\your_project_name>adb shell
your_emulator_name:/ # cd /data/data
your_emulator_name:/data/data # ls -al


If you want to copy files to and from a device, open a new Android Adb Command Prompt window and use pull and push:

C:\Users\admin\source\repos\your_project_name>adb pull /data/data/com.google.android.gm e:/app

It means copy com.google.android.gm to your computer E disk. If successfully, you will see this message:
C:\Users\admin\source\repos\your_project_name>adb pull /data/data/com.google.android.gm e:/app
/data/data/com.google.android.gm/: 39 files pulled, 0 skipped. 5.8 MB/s (985520 bytes in 0.163s)

